# How to put a comma between city and state in addressfield display?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I'm using the [addressfield](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module with Drupal 7.10.  I want a comma after the city name when displaying the addressfield.  Currently addresses display like:

```
123 Main St
SomeCity California 90100
```

I want it to display like:

```
123 Main St
SomeCity, California 90100
```

(Note the comma after "SomeCity")

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

This whole formatting of addresses is still shrouded in mystery for me.  I'm starting to think the way to control the formatting is to create a custom ctools plugin.  I found this api documentation:

http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/addressfield/addressfield.module/group/addressfield_format/7

I'm going to explore it.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually pretty simple, once you know the hooks and have some example code. You're correct that you need to use the ctools plugin api. So in a custom module, add:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ctools_plugin_directory().
 */
function mymodule_ctools_plugin_directory($module, $plugin) {
  if ($module == 'addressfield') {
    return 'plugins/addressfield/' . $plugin;
  }
}
```

Then you drop plugin files in the directory you specified, within your custom module. In this case, plugins/addressfield. A file that will do what you're looking for would contain something like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * city-comma.inc
 *
 * Adding comma after city.
 */

/**
 * Plugin definition for address field format.
 */
$plugin = array(
  'title' => t('Comma after city.'),
  'format callback' => 'mymodule_city_comma',
  'type' => 'address',
  'weight' => -80,
);

/**
 * Callback for plugin definition.
 */
function mymodule_city_comma(&$format, $address, $context = array()) {
  if (in_array($address['country'], array('US', 'CA'))) {
    if ($context['mode'] == 'render') {
      // Add comma after city.
      $format['locality_block']['locality']['#suffix'] = ',';
    }
  }
}
```

This file would actually go in a directory called 'formats' inside the directory defined in the hook. So: `mymodule/plugins/formats/city-comma.inc`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, but this needs some PHP skill.

Basically, you're going to override theme function responsble for rendering this field, which is `theme_addressfield_container()` in this case.

From function's declaration in [theme_addressfield_container()](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/addressfield--addressfield.module/function/theme_addressfield_container/DC) you can see that all address attributes are being imploded. You can easily override this function to get the result that you want.

Comment: Do you mean replacing this line `$output .= $element['#children'];` with code the creates html strings for the street, city, state, zip as desired?

Answer (score 1):

Open your theme folder, Put this code in template.php

```
<?php
// Putting comma between City and State of address field
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_addressfield_container(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if($element['#title'] == 'City') {
    $element['#children'] = trim($element['#children']) . ',';
  }
  $element['#children'] = trim($element['#children']);
  if (strlen($element['#children']) > 0) {
    $output = '<' . $element['#tag'] . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>';
    $output .= $element['#children'];
    $output .= '</' . $element['#tag'] . ">";
    return $output;
  }
  else {
    return '';
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that [Addressfield](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield) uses Ctools plugins.

I suggest you take a look [What are Ctools plugin (content type, access, etc), and how does one create them?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/how-does-one-create-a-new-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc) where I show how to create new plugins.